# Adding an index to a SQL table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing, select-into

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I am creating a table using

```
Select.. 
Into... 
From
```

where the `From` is actually 2 joined tables.

Will the resultant table have the indexes of the original tables?

Comment: No, you have to create them afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could try this yourself and see. But the answer is no. It will have a table schema consisting of the columns and types in the Select clause, but no indexes, foreign keys or anything from the source table(s).

Comment: Thanks, Randy.  I created a non-clustered index after the fact.

Comment: it helps to right click objects in the object explorer of SSMS (if you use that) and the click "SCRIPT for..." and then choose "CREATE in". This can be done with tables, indexes and a lot more. Saves time but needs proper adjustment of names of new objects.